# Is the probability of the union of $N$ sets increasing in all terms? i.e., $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$ is increasing in $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Tags: probability

I wonder if the pprobability of the union of $N$ independent events $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup ...A_N)$ is increasing in all its terms when it is decomposed. To be more precise Let $N=2$ then the intersection of two tests can be given as $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$, which  can be translated to some function of two variables  $f(x,y)=x+y-xy$. It is obvious that $f(x,y)$ is increasing in both $x$ and $y$. In a similar way, if we write the intersection of $3$ events we will have the function $$f(x,y,z)=x+y+z-(xy+xz+yz)+xyz$$ which is also increasing in all $3$ terms $x$, $y$ and $z$. If $N$ is $4$ or $5$ or in general $N$, do we have any proof which shows that $f(x,y,z,...)$ is increasing in $x,y,z,..$?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for previous confusing post.

Comment: May you explain a little bit further what are you asking for ? What are "terms" of sets : their elements ? If you are consider "usual" sets what kind of operation on them you are considering with "+" and "-" ? Thanks ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA please see the edit. I think it is okay now. Please let me know if there are some more issues. I was confused.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am talking about "Principle of inclusion and exclusion"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA are you able to understand the question now? please feel free to edit. I will really appreciate.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i think my question is slightly different isnt it? I want to see the monotonicity property.

Comment: and I must take the derivative w.r.t. all variables and who that is it always positive?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No. Symbolically I change all $\cap$ at the right hand side to multiplication and this gives me a function as I described. $x$ and $y$ are not actually the sets they represent the probabilites coming from those sets. $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$. Okay this is the one!

Comment: Note that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ is not true in general; it's only true when $A,B$ are independent events.

Comment: @NateEldredge i edited the question including the information about independency of the events.

Comment: Please replace "intersection" by "union", three times in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If the events $(A_i)$ are independent,* then
$$
P(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_N)=1-P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap\cdots\cap A_N^c)=1-\prod_{i=1}^NP(A_i^c),
$$
hence
$$
P(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_N)=G(P(A_1),P(A_2),\ldots,P(A_N)),
$$
where
$$
G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)=1-\prod_{i=1}^N(1-x_i),
$$
that is, yes, $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_N)$ is a nondecreasing function of each argument $P(A_i)$.

Comment: sorry forgot to replace it, edited. By the way thanks for the answer. The question was about this MO question and the following answer, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155478/comparing-the-stopping-times-of-two-stochastic-processes.